# Telegram Botman - getBotMessages not working

Tags: laravel, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, botman

Hi i need the last message id that send with bot
and i want to get last message bot in conversation
`$this->bot->getBotMessages();`
when i print that on serialize
`$this->bot->reply($this->bot->getBotMessages());`
to then get id with this way
`getPayload()['message_id']`
return this
`a:0:{}`

i want this for reply to the last bot message

this is my code

```
    $text = "Hello world";

    $parameters = [
        'chat_id' => $this->bot->getBotMessages()[0]->getPayload()['chat']['id'],
        'reply_to_message_id' => $this->bot->getBotMessages()[0]->getPayload()['message_id'],
        'text' => $text
    ];
    $this->bot->sendRequest('sendMessage',$parameters);
```

Comment: you need to specify more, the language of your question is unclear & incomplete, explain what you are using as well

Comment: I'm guessing `getBotMessages` is used in backend of your bot engine to get and process last updates. see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getupdates . getUpdates is used to get the latest updates from users not the messages sent by your bot. You should store messages in a database if you want to process them later. Other than that, you can send a message with your bot and see what is the latest id in a chat is in returned response.